# Ionic 3 PWA app breakpoints and source code in the browser are messed up

Tags: ionic-framework, browser, breakpoints, source-maps

I cannot put breakpoints in the correct position because it seems to be showing an older version of the sources in the browser.

How can I force it to update the source in the browser?

Comment: Sometimes browsers cache data, try using Ctrl + F5 (Or Ctrl + refresh button) to trigger hard refresh, it might help with your problem.

Comment: Ctrl + F5 not working. It seems to be the same unsync source code in different browsers.

Comment: I have this problem from time to time, for me it always worked stopping the ionic serve process and restarting it

Comment: Not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It seems to be caused by decorators occupying multiple lines like this:

```
@IonicPage({
    name: 'my-page',
    segment: 'my-page/:id',
    defaultHistory: ['my-other-page']
})
@Component({
    selector: 'my-page',
    templateUrl: 'my-page-cotacao.html',
    providers: [BrMaskerIonic3]
})
```

The solution is to set each decorator in a single line, like this:

```
@IonicPage({ name: 'my-page', segment: 'my-page/:id',    defaultHistory: ['my-other-page'] })
@Component({ selector: 'my-page', templateUrl: 'my-page.html', providers: [BrMaskerIonic3] })
```

Answer (score 0):

During development its best to leverage chrome devtools > application tab > service worker section. Basically you can set "bypass" service worker cache and other settings to help you use the latest:

[image]

Another approach is to modify your caching strategy from default one to "network first":

In your service worker do:

```
// dynamically cache any other local assets
self.toolbox.router.any('/*', self.toolbox.networkFirst);

// for any other requests go to the network, cache,
// and then only use that cached resource if your user goes offline
self.toolbox.router.default = self.toolbox.networkFirst;
```

Comment: It already is this way but still doesn’t works. Maybe this error is related to the source maps.